# IBM Liberty18.0.0.1 : LinkageError class-loader issue Cxf

Tags: cxf, classloader, websphere-liberty

**Objective**: Trying to deploy two appliactions that both use cxf for webservicesa

**App1** : ejbws.ear : ejb-with @WebService annotation. Liberty exposes this as  webservice using cxf bus that is already available in container.

**App2**: myapp.war. A springboot webapp that has some soap services

**Observation 1**: If I "dropin" App1 alone, the soap services in it work. If I dropin App2 alone the soap service in it work.

**Observation 2 :** If I dropin both, depending upon which one is picked up faster, only one of those work, the other encounters LinkageError.

**Potential problem:**
 - Looks like there is a class loader clash for org/apache/cxf/service/Service

**Requirements:**

1. Make sure App1 ejbws-ear uses container cxf (as cxf dependency is not present in that ear file)
2. Make sure App2 sbootapp.war, uses cxf lib that is bundled with the war
3. App2 should work without any pom changes in cmdline/tomcat and other containers. I.e don't use any shared library

**Try1** : use "parent last"  config for both application. No success.

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>websocket-1.1</feature>
    <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
    <feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
    <feature>httpWhiteboard-1.0</feature>
    <feature>osgiConsole-1.0</feature>
    <feature>mediaServerControl-1.0</feature>
    <feature>productInsights-1.0</feature>
    <feature>mpFaultTolerance-1.0</feature>
    <feature>apiDiscovery-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>


    <!-- this parentlast did not help --><enterpriseApplication type="ear" location="D:\apps\ibmliberty-18001\usr\servers\defaultServer\dropins\ejb_earws.ear" tname="ejb_earws">
    <classloader delegation="parentLast"/>
   </enterpriseApplication>
   <enterpriseApplication type="war" location="D:\apps\ibmliberty-18001\usr\servers\defaultServer\dropins\mysboot-1.0.war" name="mysboot">
    <classloader delegation="parentLast"/>
   </enterpriseApplication>
```

**Try 2** :  what else should I try?

**Trace dump:**

```
------Start of DE processing------ = [14/05/18 12:29:29:634 EDT]
Exception = org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
Source = com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost
probeid = startWebApp
Stack Dump = org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xyz' defined in class path resource [org/mst/test/integration/conf/WebConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.xml.ws.Endpoint]: Factory method 'xyz' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(Lorg/apache/cxf/service/Service;)V" the class loader (instance of com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/AppClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/cxf/jaxb/JAXBDataBinding, and its superclass loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader), have different Class objects for the type org/apache/cxf/service/Service used in the signature
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:134)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebApp.java:2495)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1002)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6574)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:467)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApplication(DynamicVirtualHost.java:462)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startWebApplication(WebContainer.java:1132)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.access$000(WebContainer.java:108)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer$3.run(WebContainer.java:944)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.xml.ws.Endpoint]: Factory method 'xyz' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(Lorg/apache/cxf/service/Service;)V" the class loader (instance of com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/AppClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/cxf/jaxb/JAXBDataBinding, and its superclass loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader), have different Class objects for the type org/apache/cxf/service/Service used in the signature
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(Lorg/apache/cxf/service/Service;)V" the class loader (instance of com/ibm/ws/classloading/internal/AppClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/cxf/jaxb/JAXBDataBinding, and its superclass loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader), have different Class objects for the type org/apache/cxf/service/Service used in the signature
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.createDefaultDataBinding(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:229)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.getDataBinding(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:109)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.getDataBinding(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:105)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.generatedWrapperBeanClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:668)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.getExtraClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:645)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:420)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:528)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:199)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:168)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:460)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:338)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:255)
    at org.mst.test.integration.conf.WebConfiguration.xyz(WebConfiguration.java:135)
    at org.mst.test.integration.conf.WebConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a5109f9f.CGLIB$xyz$9(<generated>)
    at org.mst.test.integration.conf.WebConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a5109f9f$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$941731ce.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at org.mst.test.integration.conf.WebConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a5109f9f.xyz(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 33 more
```

**Dump of callerThis**

```
Object type = [Ljava.lang.Object;
  Object[0] = class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost@1d03cafa
    tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@5886fbf5
      strings[0] = "TraceComponent[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost,class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost,[webcontainer],com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.resources.LShimMessages,null]"
    CLASS_NAME = "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost"
    webContainerParent = class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer@66141d9d
      tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@3229c23c
      CLASS_NAME = "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer"
      initialized = true
      eventService = class com.ibm.ws.event.internal.EventEngineImpl@1c29644d
      futureMonitor = class com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.FutureMonitorImpl@72220f91
      classLoadingSRRef = class com.ibm.wsspi.kernel.service.utils.AtomicServiceReference@672facda
      sessionHelperSRRef = class com.ibm.wsspi.kernel.service.utils.AtomicServiceReference@36663023
      cacheManagerSRRef = class com.ibm.wsspi.kernel.service.utils.AtomicServiceReference@61ba21ae
      injectionEngineSRRef = class com.ibm.wsspi.kernel.service.utils.AtomicServiceReference@306f48f
      managedObjectServiceSRRef = class com.ibm.wsspi.kernel.service.utils.AtomicServiceReference@19d5d149
      backgroundWebAppStartFutures = class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.util.OneTimeUseArrayList@1eb51d78
      REFERENCE_WEB_MBEAN_RUNTIME = "webMBeanRuntime"
      webMBeanRuntimeServiceRef = class com.ibm.wsspi.kernel.service.utils.AtomicServiceReference@2eb2e851
      servletContainerInitializers = class com.ibm.wsspi.kernel.service.utils.ConcurrentServiceReferenceSet@1aa4c384
      es = class com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl@2d4c1600
      locationServiceRef = class java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference@1b24900c
      transferContextServiceRef = class com.ibm.wsspi.kernel.service.utils.ConcurrentServiceReferenceSet@226d0359
      encodingServiceRef = class java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference@1e694c73
      instance = class java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference@53d8a5a8
      vhostManager = class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHostManager@6c43fb2f
      metaDataService = class com.ibm.ws.container.service.metadata.internal.MetaDataServiceImpl@5c12af5b
      j2eeNameFactory = class com.ibm.ws.container.service.metadata.internal.J2EENameFactoryImpl@1bb315e2
      context = class org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ComponentContextImpl@26fe4a35
      contextRoots = class java.util.Collections$SynchronizedSet@72a0804d
      pendingContextRoots = class java.util.HashMap@64c38e54
      deployedModuleMap = class java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@172a9b60
      connContextPool = class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.srt.factory.SRTConnectionContextPool31Impl@43d1d452
      DEFAULT_PORT = "*"
      DEFAULT_VHOST_NAME = "default_host"
      cachedServerInfo = "IBM WebSphere Liberty/${liberty.service.version}"
      lock = class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer$1@3585968d
      webAppFactory = class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.webapp.factory.WebAppFactoryImpl31@4d4c1f47
      requestFactory = class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.response.factory.IRequestResponseFactory@efe6c15
      responseFactory = class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.response.factory.IRequestResponseFactory@efe6c15
      asyncContextFactory = class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.async.factory.AsyncContextFactory31Impl@43404adc
      DEFAULT_MAX_VERSION = 30
      versionRef = class org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceReferenceImpl@5ae88dc7
      serverStopping = class com.ibm.ws.staticvalue.StaticValue$FinalSingleton@77f307fa
      modulesStarting = 0
      uriMatcherFactory = class com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer31.util.factory.URIMatcherFactory31Impl@a1053d5
      SPEC_LEVEL_UNLOADED = -1
      SPEC_LEVEL_30 = 30
      SPEC_LEVEL_31 = 31
      SPEC_LEVEL_40 = 40
      DEFAULT_SPEC_LEVEL = 30
      loadedContainerSpecLevel = 31
      ISO = "ISO-8859-1"
      encoding = "UTF-8"
      decode = true
      wcconfig = class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainerConfiguration@555fd4fb
      applicationListeners = class java.util.ArrayList@3a7cd57d
      servletListeners = class java.util.ArrayList@327aa71c
      servletErrorListeners = class java.util.ArrayList@463e6754
      servletInvocationListeners = class java.util.ArrayList@6ded8b64
      filterInvocationListeners = class java.util.ArrayList@31e67c99
      filterErrorListeners = class java.util.ArrayList@56c37ffe
      filterListeners = class java.util.ArrayList@63f2b6b5
      servletRequestListeners = class java.util.ArrayList@62c5a704
      servletRequestAttributeListeners = class java.util.ArrayList@60c50d71
      servletContextListeners = class java.util.ArrayList@2db4a218
      servletContextAttributeListeners = class java.util.ArrayList@5b05ee05
      sessionListeners = class java.util.ArrayList@14379fe6
      sessionIdListeners = class java.util.ArrayList@5c51a694
      sessionAttributeListeners = class java.util.ArrayList@54fd6b64
      DEFAULT_HOST = "default_host"
      _initialized = true
      logger = class com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.WsLogger@66e689a2
      CLASS_NAME = "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.internal.WebContainer"
      nls = class com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceNLS@20fcd238
      self = class java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference@81cb16e
      _cipherToBit = class java.util.HashMap@59a8d3ff
      cacheKeyStringBuilder = class com.ibm.ws.util.WSThreadLocal@66b125e5
      listenersInitialized = true
      webConProperties = class java.util.Properties@201a5619
      sessionRegistry = null
      isStopped = false
      readWriteLockForStopping = class java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock@4d6014b5
      urlPrefix = ";jsessionid="
      extensionFactories = class java.util.ArrayList@10ca33f7
      postInitExtensionFactories = null
      httpResponseListeners = class java.util.ArrayList@52c801cd
      servletContainerInitializers = class java.util.ServiceLoader@3db9887c
      auditManager = class com.ibm.websphere.security.audit.context.AuditManager@4f61bb4c
      threadLocal = class java.lang.ThreadLocal@2e9cba9
      invocationCacheSize = 500
      decodePlusSign = true
      _cacheMap = class java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@10bd6450
      _cacheSize = class java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger@61b6e453
      vHostCompatFlag = false
      platformHelper = class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.PlatformHelper@234f88f2
      isDefaultTempDir = true
      tempDir = null
      servletCachingInitNeeded = true
      appInstallBegun = true
      cacheServletWrapperFactory = class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.servlet.factory.CacheServletWrapperFactory31Impl@6fb7bbb1
      commands = class java.util.ArrayList@1453cdf3
      requestMapper = class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.util.VirtualHostContextRootMapper@42112756
      parent = null
      name = "Was.webcontainer"
      isAlive = true
      subElements = class java.util.HashMap@1d462ffe
      attributes = null
      config = null
      serialVersionUID = -8271459000149267764
      $$$tc$$$ = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@7e7b2f1f
    dhostConfig = class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHostConfiguration@70bf7c92
      tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@48ce66cc
      name = "default_host"
      activeContexts = class java.util.HashSet@435da80b
      tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@880f3e
      config = class com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl@75899a9b
      _id = "default_host"
      _attributes = null
      serialVersionUID = 7511545662945734886
      $$$tc$$$ = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@2646ee62
    predefinedMatcher = null
    normalizeRequestURI = false
    logger = class com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.WsLogger@66e689a2
      tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@26dc46a0
      ivCachedResourceBundleName = "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.resources.Messages"
      ivCachedResourceBundle = class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.resources.Messages@24178af5
      ivComponent = null
      ivOrganization = null
      ivProduct = null
      ivMinimumLocalizationLevelIntValue = 625
      ivTC = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@1975ee4f
      loggerRegistrationComponent = class java.lang.ThreadLocal@4d6b6b9a
      emptyHandlers = class java.util.logging.Handler[0]
      offValue = 2147483647
      SYSTEM_LOGGER_RB_NAME = "sun.util.logging.resources.logging"
      SYSTEM_BUNDLE = class java.util.logging.Logger$LoggerBundle@5ddc8c5b
      NO_RESOURCE_BUNDLE = class java.util.logging.Logger$LoggerBundle@7fa319cb
      manager = class com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.logging.WsLogManager@677b74e8
      name = "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer"
      handlers = class java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList@715ae426
      loggerBundle = class java.util.logging.Logger$LoggerBundle@48dd1002
      useParentHandlers = true
      filter = null
      anonymous = false
      catalog = class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.resources.Messages@24178af5
      catalogName = "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.resources.Messages"
      catalogLocale = class java.util.Locale@2fd72593
      treeLock = class java.lang.Object@1337d8b5
      parent = class java.util.logging.Logger@1fccced1
      kids = class java.util.ArrayList@356a6521
      levelObject = class java.util.logging.Level@15172e8e
      levelValue = 800
      callersClassLoaderRef = class java.lang.ref.WeakReference@3fa7a02
      isSystemLogger = false
      GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME = "global"
      global = class java.util.logging.Logger@2e25e8b8
      $assertionsDisabled = true
    CLASS_NAME = "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHost"
    vHostConfig = class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHostConfiguration@70bf7c92
    commands = class java.util.ArrayList@20589816
      serialVersionUID = 8683452581122892189
      DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10
      EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA = class java.lang.Object[0]
      DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA = class java.lang.Object[0]
      elementData = class java.lang.Object[3]
      size = 0
      MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 2147483639
      modCount = 0
      MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 2147483639
    requestMapper = class com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.URIMapper@2b883b63
      matcher = class com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.URIMatcher@5d46850
    parent = class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer@66141d9d
    name = "default_host"
    isAlive = true
    subElements = class java.util.HashMap@5c200e43
      serialVersionUID = 362498820763181265
      DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16
      MAXIMUM_CAPACITY = 1073741824
      DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75
      TREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 8
      UNTREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 6
      MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY = 64
      table = class java.util.HashMap$Node[16]
      entrySet = null
      size = 12
      modCount = 12
      threshold = 12
      loadFactor = 0.75
      keySet = null
      values = null
    attributes = null
    config = null
    serialVersionUID = -8271459000149267764
    $$$tc$$$ = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@7e7b2f1f
      strings[0] = "TraceComponent[com.ibm.ws.container.AbstractContainer,class com.ibm.ws.container.AbstractContainer,[],null,null]"
  Object[1] = class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.webapp.WebApp31@30b89036
    tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@2653c192
      strings[0] = "TraceComponent[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.webapp.WebApp31,class com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.webapp.WebApp31,[webcontainer],com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.resources.Messages,null]"
    CLASS_NAME = "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.webapp.WebApp31"
    servlet31NLS = class com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceNLS@e5927fc
      resolver = class com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.TraceNLSResolver@e50e245
      finder = class com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.StackFinder@229a1826
      ivBundleName = "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.resources.Messages"
      caller = class java.lang.Class@211a906d
    validListenerClasses = class java.lang.Class[7]
      Class[0] = class java.lang.Class@6f19cee7
      Class[1] = class java.lang.Class@2f7d79ae
      Class[2] = class java.lang.Class@114b4540
      Class[3] = class java.lang.Class@16bb19a
      Class[4] = class java.lang.Class@20a439a6
      Class[5] = class java.lang.Class@64508415
      Class[6] = class java.lang.Class@3fc5eeb5
    wsocServHandler = class com.ibm.ws.wsoc.external.WsocHandlerImpl@9ceb1d
      tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@79edbdf9
      noMoreAddsCalled = false
      serialVersionUID = -2067291126638824067
    tc = class com.ibm.websphere.ras.TraceComponent@4fe83a5d
      strings[0] =
```

Comment: What does your server.xml look like?  If both of your apps package the CXF libraries that you need, then you might be able to resolve this situation by removing Liberty's built-in CXF - you would need to remove the `jaxrs-2.0` and/or `jaxws-2.2` features.

Comment: added the server.xml details. the App1:ejbws relies on container to autogenerate the webservice routers for the ejb interface, so it does not package any cxf libraries.  The App2:springboot  does have all dependent wars inside.

Comment: Can you try getting rid of the javaee-7.0 and webProfile-7.0 features?  You might need to add back some of the features that they pull in depending on what your application depends on.  Make sure not to pull in jaxrs-2.0 or jaxws-2.2.  Then you should be able to run CXF without conflicting with the CXF that comes with Liberty.  You may also need to add the JAX-WS or JAX-RS API jars to your application.

Comment: Alternatively, maybe you could remove the CXF jars from your app and just use the CXF that ships with Liberty.

Comment: @AndyMcCright - (1) Removing cxf-jars from App2 would invalidate my Requirement3. i.e the app should work in standalone/tomcat deployments.  (2) Removing cxf-jars from <feature> will make App1 not work. A working "parent-last" would SOLVE my issue. Is there a place were we can escalate for a quickfix in liberty to fix "parent last" ? This use-case seems normal to expect in a j2ee container I suppose.

Comment: Hi @Gas of IBM. "parent last" class loading, must work right? Can you please escalate to IBM for a fix? Please let them know the requirement: App1 must use cxf-jars of container. App2 must use self-packaged cxf jars, with parent-last. Both App1&2 must run in same container.

Comment: As you saw, separately it works, so they clash with each other. Why App1&2 must run in same container? they are separate apps. You can create PMR in support, but I doubt it will work in a way you describe ;-).

Comment: I wish IBM could acknowledge "parent last" is not working in liberty (a bug to be fixed).